# I have several Postgresql versions. How can I make sure it runs the one I need&

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-20.04

I have three versions of PG install on may Ubuntu 20.04:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres
```

However, I only need one of them -- 9.6. Is there a way to choose version, like we choose with rvm, for example? Or should I destroy the versions I don't need?

I have tried to run this command `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6 postgresql-contrib` but it still installs the 13 version.

And when I check for version with `sudo -u postgres psql`, `SELECT version();` it shows me 13th versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! :)

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6` did the trick, it installed only 9.6 version.

Comment: Unless you also uninstalled the other versions you still have three versions.  What repos are you using?

Comment: Yes, I undertand that. I have deleted all postgres packages from the machine, then downloaded just the one I needed.

Comment: I always have my different versions using different ports: 54396 for version 9.6, port 54310 for version 10, etc. With one major release every year, I'll be fine during my lifetime ;-)